# angularjs custom filter not working in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-filter

The custom `filter:searchFilter` working fine in normal html here is the demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Oyydxa on the other hand the same function doesn't working in ionic framework.

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="filterName">
<ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="leaf in leafs | filter:searchFilter" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/leafs/{{leaf.id}}">
```

filter

```
$scope.searchFilter = function(obj) {
    var re = new RegExp($scope.filterName, 'i');
    return !$scope.filterName || re.test(obj.botanical_name) || re.test(obj.en_names) || re.test(obj.ml_names);
};
```

**ionic demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjjGWo**

Unfortunately the `console.log($scope.filterName)` seems to me as empty. Is there any solution to fix this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `ng-controller="MyCtrl"` attribute from the `<div ng-app="ionicApp">` container, onto the `<ion-content>`, like so:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="MyCtrl">
```

Here's a [modified codepen](http://codepen.io/olliebennett/pen/MaaLRe?editors=101).